# How to prove that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{(x^n)'}{(n-1)!} = e^{x}(x-1)$

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I am trying to prove that $$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{\left(x^n\right)'}{\left(n-1\right)!} = e^{x}(x+1)\tag 1$$

---

This sum is very similar to the derivative of exponential $(e^x)' = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(x^{n})'}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ but there is that $n$ factor that I can't get rid off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Should the sum be from $n=1$? If not, how is $(-1)!$ defined?

Comment: Write the right hand side as a power series and show that both power series have corresponding coefficients.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1+1)x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\
&=
x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}
+
e^x\\
&=
e^x(x+1).
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $x^n=x\cdot x^{n-1}$ the product rule says that $(x^n)'=(x\cdot x^{n-1})'=x^{n-1}+(n-1)x\cdot x^{n-2}.$

Answer (score 3):

An alternative version.

$$\int_0^x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x^n)'}{(n-1)!}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!} = x \sum_{n-1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = x \cdot e^x$$

Derivate the result and you get

$$(x e^x)' = e^x+xe^x = (1+x)e^x$$